# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

Am trying to configure HibernateSearch for ElasticSearch Integration. 
I have `Product` table in my oracle database. From that table am trying to search based on product name.

For that am trying to integrate HibernateSearch (ElasticSearch) along with oracle database.

Am getting the below error from HibernateSearch :

Am using Oracle database and added the required dependencies in my pom.xml file

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a subclass of an indexed entity
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.MassIndexerImpl.toRootEntities(MassIndexerImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.MassIndexerImpl.<init>(MassIndexerImpl.java:63)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.DefaultMassIndexerFactory.createMassIndexer(DefaultMassIndexerFactory.java:33)
at org.hibernate.search.impl.FullTextSessionImpl.createIndexer(FullTextSessionImpl.java:175)
at com.test.webservice.elasticsearch.App.doIndex(App.java:36)
at com.test.webservice.elasticsearch.App.main(App.java:109)
```

Am using all the latest dependencies.

```
hibernate-search-orm ->5.9.1.Final
hibernate-core ->5.2.16.Final`
ojdbc14 -> 10.2.0.4.0
```

App.java

```
public class App 
{

    private static void doIndex() throws InterruptedException {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();   // Error occuring on this line

        fullTextSession.close();
    }

    private static List<Product> search(String queryString) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Product.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("name").matching(queryString).createQuery();

        // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
        org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Product.class);

        List<Product> productList = fullTextQuery.list();

        fullTextSession.close();

        return productList;
    }

    private static void displayContactTableData() {
        Session session = null;
        PropertiesFile propertiesFile= PropertiesFile.getInstance();
        String driverClass = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class");
        String connectionURL = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.connection.url");
        String userName = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.connection.username");
        String password = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.connection.password");
        String dialect = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.dialect");
        String showSQL = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.show_sql");

        try {
            //session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

            // Fetching saved data
            String hql = "from Product"; 
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

             Configuration cfg=new Configuration()
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driverClass)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", connectionURL)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", userName)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password)
            .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect)
            .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", showSQL)
            .addAnnotatedClass(com.test.webservice.model.Product.class);

             SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  
             session=factory.openSession();  
             Transaction t=session.beginTransaction(); 

            List<Product> productList = session.createQuery(hql).list();

            for (Product product : productList) {
                System.out.println("Product Name --->"+product.getName());
            }

        } catch(HibernateException exception){
             System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
             exception.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("\n\n******Data stored in Contact table******\n");
        displayContactTableData();

        // Create an initial Lucene index for the data already present in the database
        doIndex();   // Error occuring on this line

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String consoleInput = null;

        while (true) {
            // Prompt the user to enter query string
            System.out.println("\n\nEnter search key (To exit type 'X')");      
            System.out.println();
            consoleInput = scanner.nextLine();

            if("X".equalsIgnoreCase(consoleInput)) {
                System.out.println("End");
                System.exit(0);
            }   

            List<Product> result = search(consoleInput);            
            System.out.println("\n\n>>>>>>Record found for '" + consoleInput + "'");

            for (Product product : result) {
                System.out.println(product);
            }               
        }           
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">vb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">C:\lucene\indexes</property>

        <mapping class="com.test.webservice.model.Product" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private long id;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is wrong, it should be "java.lang.Object is not an indexed entity or a **superclass** of an indexed entity". I [created a ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3134), we'll fix the error message ASAP.

Regarding your problem, this exception means neither `Object` nor any of its subclasses is indexed. In short, there isn't any indexed class.

I can see that your `Product` class is annotated with `@Indexed`, so this probably means there is a problem with how you start Hibernate ORM in `HibernateUtil`.

The simple fact that you commented your line `session = HibernateUtil.getSession();` in `displayContactTableData()` makes me think you already knew that, though.

You should have a look at the [getting started guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial_annotations) to make sure you start Hibernate ORM correctly.

Comment: still this error persist., not sure how to solve this issue and how this is coming.??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I changed my import from `import org.springframework.stereotype.Indexed;` to `import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;` and it worked!!