# Can't build query for type 'x.y.z.package' which is neither configured nor has any configured sub-types

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

Am trying to configure HibernateSearch for ElasticSearch Integration. 
I have `Product` table in my oracle database. From that table am trying to search based on product name.

For that am trying to integrate HibernateSearch (ElasticSearch) along with oracle database.

Am getting the below error from HibernateSearch :

Am using Oracle database and added the required dependencies in my pom.xml file

Enter search key (To exit type 'X')

```
JT3312
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000331: Can't build query for type 'com.test.webservice.model.Product' which is neither configured nor has any configured sub-types.
at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedQueryContextBuilder$HSearchEntityContext.<init>(ConnectedQueryContextBuilder.java:60)
at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedQueryContextBuilder.forEntity(ConnectedQueryContextBuilder.java:42)
at com.test.webservice.elasticsearch.App.search(App.java:74)
at com.test.webservice.elasticsearch.App.main(App.java:153)
```

Am using all the latest dependencies.

```
hibernate-search-orm ->5.9.1.Final
hibernate-core ->5.2.16.Final`
ojdbc14 -> 10.2.0.4.0
```

App.java

```
public class App 
{

    private static void doIndex() throws InterruptedException {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();   

        fullTextSession.close();
    }

    private static List<Product> search(String queryString) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Product.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("name").matching(queryString).createQuery();

        // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
        org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Product.class);

        List<Product> productList = fullTextQuery.list();

        fullTextSession.close();

        return productList;
    }

    private static void displayContactTableData() {
        Session session = null;
        PropertiesFile propertiesFile= PropertiesFile.getInstance();
        String driverClass = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class");
        String connectionURL = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.connection.url");
        String userName = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.connection.username");
        String password = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.connection.password");
        String dialect = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.dialect");
        String showSQL = propertiesFile.extractPropertiesFile().getProperty("hibernate.show_sql");

        try {
            //session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

            // Fetching saved data
            String hql = "from Product"; 
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

             Configuration cfg=new Configuration()
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driverClass)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", connectionURL)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", userName)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password)
            .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect)
            .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", showSQL)
            .addAnnotatedClass(com.test.webservice.model.Product.class);

             SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  
             session=factory.openSession();  
             Transaction t=session.beginTransaction(); 

            List<Product> productList = session.createQuery(hql).list();

            for (Product product : productList) {
                System.out.println("Product Name --->"+product.getName());
            }

        } catch(HibernateException exception){
             System.out.println("Problem creating session factory");
             exception.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("\n\n******Data stored in Contact table******\n");
        displayContactTableData();

        // Create an initial Lucene index for the data already present in the database
        doIndex();   // Error occuring on this line

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String consoleInput = null;

        while (true) {
            // Prompt the user to enter query string
            System.out.println("\n\nEnter search key (To exit type 'X')");      
            System.out.println();
            consoleInput = scanner.nextLine();

            if("X".equalsIgnoreCase(consoleInput)) {
                System.out.println("End");
                System.exit(0);
            }   

            List<Product> result = search(consoleInput);            
            System.out.println("\n\n>>>>>>Record found for '" + consoleInput + "'");

            for (Product product : result) {
                System.out.println(product);
            }               
        }           
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">vb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">C:\lucene\indexes</property>

        <mapping class="com.test.webservice.model.Product" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I [answered to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50015871/6692043), the problem is very likely to be in how you bootstrap Hibernate in `HibernateUtil`. Very probably you forgot a call to `addAnnotatedClass`.

Ask yourself why you had to comment this line in `displayContactTableData`:

```
        //session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
```

There's obviously something wrong in your `HibernateUtil`, so fix it instead of avoiding it in some places and not in others.